# Open ContextMenu from MenuItem click

Tags: android, android-menu, android-contextmenu

I need to open a context menu on MenuItem click. How can i do this? I've tried to do this on BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener:

```
registerForContextMenu(menuItem.actionView)
openContextMenu(menuItem.actionView)
```

but the actionView in null.

Thanks a lot.

Main Activity:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
                navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
                navigation.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_dashboard
            }
        }

        private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
...
                R.id.navigation_add -> {
                    registerForContextMenu(menuItem.actionView)
                    openContextMenu(item.actionView)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
            }
            false
        }

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
                navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
                navigation.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_dashboard
            }


        override fun onCreateContextMenu(menu: ContextMenu, v: View,
                                         menuInfo: ContextMenuInfo) {
            ...

        }

        override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            ...
        }
```